# How to add nested resolver to schema?

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

Let's say my query looks like this:

```
query {
  post {
    id
    user { id, name } 
  }
}
```

And resolver map looks like this:

```
{
  Query: {
    post: myPostResolverFunc,
  }
}
```

How I can add additional "nested" resolver for post.user?
I tried this but it does not work:

```
addResolveFunctionsToSchema(schema, {
  Query: {
    post: {
      user: postUserResolveFunc,
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to write a resolver for your field. Assuming your schema is something like this :

```
type Post {
  id: ID!,
  user: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!,
  username: String!
}

type Query {
  post(id: ID!): Post  #assuming you want to request a simple post here
}
```

You can write resolvers like this :

```
addResolveFunctionsToSchema(schema, {
  Post: {
    user(root) {
      return getUserById(root.user)
    }
  }
  Query: {
    post(root, args, context) {
      return getPostById(args.id)
    }
  }
});
```